# Как сделать проверку на загруженное фото?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота на node js. Подскажите как правильно этот код засунуть в конструкцию switch?

if(msg.photo) {
               const src = './src/photos/TS/Заземление ODU/' + helper.datetime();

```
            fs.mkdir(src, function() {
                const raw = msg.photo[3].file_id;
                bot.downloadFile(raw, src);
            });

            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Мы получили выше фото. Спасибо.')
        } else  {
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Вы не отправили фото. Пожалуйста, загрузите фото!')
        }
```

В головном проекте этот способ не работает, пишет polling error, даже когда не в конструкции switch, а на тестовом боте всё нормально. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял нужно `if` и `else` в суитчер поместить

```js
switch (msg.photo) {
    case null:
        const src = './src/photos/TS/Заземление ODU/' + helper.datetime();
        
        fs.mkdir(src, function() {
            const raw = msg.photo[3].file_id;
            bot.downloadFile(raw, src);
        });
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Мы получили выше фото. Спасибо.')
        break;

    default:
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Вы не отправили фото. Пожалуйста, загрузите фото!')
        break;
}
```

Ну или поместить все это в суитч

```js
switch (msg.text) {
    case "Заземление":
        if(msg.photo) 
        { 
            const src = './src/photos/TS/Заземление ODU/' + helper.datetime();
            fs.mkdir(src, function() {
                const raw = msg.photo[3].file_id;
                bot.downloadFile(raw, src);
            });
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Мы получили выше фото. Спасибо.')
        } else  {
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Вы не отправили фото. Пожалуйста, загрузите фото!')
        }
        break;
}
```